# Jest - test callback calls inside a recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a helper function that iterates over a query cursor, and calls a callback over the results. It looks a bit like this:

```js
async function recursiveFunction(callback: () => Promise<any>): Promise<void> {
  const result = await callback();
  if (result.hasNext) recursiveFunction(callback);
}

describe('recursiveFunction', () => {
  const NUMBER_OF_CALLS = 6;
  const mockCallback = jest.fn();

  mockCallback.mockResolvedValue({ hasNext: false });
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CALLS - 1; i += 1) {
    mockCallback.mockResolvedValueOnce({ hasNext: true });
  }

  describe('When there are no errors', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await recursiveFunction(mockCallback);
    });

    it(`should have called callback ${NUMBER_OF_CALLS} times`, () => {
      expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(NUMBER_OF_CALLS);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is, that it seems to "lose track" of the `mockCallback` after a couple of iterations (for this test case, anything over 4):

```sh
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 6
    Received number of calls: 4
```

```sh
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 8
    Received number of calls: 4
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without doing something like wrapping my recursive function inside a class and keeping it just as an exported function.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you forgot to `return`, in  your `recursiveFunction` function. You're not waiting for the recursive calls to be made: `if (result.hasNext) return recursiveFunction(callback);`.

Comment: I feel kinda dumb now, that did it. Thanks @blex!